# Routing with Component-based Directives in Angular 1.3?

Tags: angularjs

I have a question about the best way to structure the flow of an app using Angular 1.3. I'm trying to incorporate the 'Component-based Directive' approach as per guys like Matias Niemela (https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/workshops/component-based-directives-angularjs). He says in a video to still  use controllers for routing rather than going completely controller-free, but to use directives to create reusable components that have all their dependencies injected.

I'm a bit new to Angular but have used Java mvc frameworks before where a controller written in Java first finishes getting the data needed on the page to be displayed, before some html is constructed and served up. I'm wondering if I'm coming a bit unstuck due to the asynchronous nature of the javascript calls used in Angular, maybe assuming things happen in an order they can't be guaranteed to....

I want to try to make the directives involved have anything they rely on injected (likely via attr's) for increased test-ability etc.

I had envisaged something like the following, for a simple customer listing, with clicking on a single customer in that list going through to a customer details page:

1) a route is defined with a target html page and a controller. 
2) The controller gets the list of customers (ideally via a service), which is then available to the html page via Controller As (so Controller MyController As myCont, means the list should be available via something like myCont.myCustomers
3) A Directive is defined to display a customer row's details (name/address, plus a clickable link that passes the customer number as a parameter to a details page)
4) The html page has an ng-repeat to display all of myCustomer in myCustomers, using the Directive. So, I would want to pass the single customer details into the directive via Attr's (for my dependency injection) and then get them displayed for each customer...

(Alternatively, of course, the directive could take in all the customers and display all of them)

So, my question is really whether this is the correct approach to take, or am I missing something about the way these apps need to flow? I've tried unsuccessfully to get it working (posting this from home and my attempt is at work... I'll post the attempt if ppl think it valuable, but really my first question is about whether my overall approach is inherently flawed or not)

And then, secondly, to get the data for each customer passed to the directive, I'm assuming I need to pass the fields in in the html page that has the directive in it, passing something like {{ myCustomer }}... is this correct? (can I assume the Controller will have finished getting all the data before the ng-Repeat tries to cycle through all my customers and send their data to the directive, or not, in which case should I be passing the data via some other mechanism?)

I can't seem to find any examples on the web that tie together Component based Directives, with routing via a Controller, passing data from that controller to the directive, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: This structure seems alright. Did it work?